# How to recursively remove all .exe files from all the subdirectories of the current directory?

Tags: linux, shell, script, awk, rm

I have a USB containing important files. However it is infiltrated with some unwanted .exe files (probably virsuses) in each subfolder. Since I am on a Linux machine, the exe files won't affect me. However I want to remove them (for personal safety).
So how do I do it using a Linux command or a shell/AWK or Python script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find /PATHTOUSBSTICK -iname "*.exe"
```

will show you all .exe files

If you are satisfied with the results (please check before deleting!) you can issue the following command:

```
find /PATHTOUSBSTICK -iname "*.exe" -exec rm {} \;
```

This will delete all matches found with the first command.

Comment: Make that "rm -- {}" to handle files whose name starts with "-".

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all the exe files present in your current and all its sub-directories:

```
 find . -name "*.exe" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU find available use `-delete` action:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -iname '*.exe' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

`find . -name "*.exe" | xargs -n 1 -I {} echo "rm {}"  > tmp.sh`

check tmp.sh in your favorite editor; when you are happy:

`/bin/sh tmp.sh`

to delete.